# NestJS: Getting MOVED error on using cache with Redis cluster

Tags: redis, nestjs, redis-cluster

I have integrated Caching using Redis Cluster on my NestJs app but am unable to save data to cache as I am getting **"MOVED 8821 109.111.123.112"** error whenever I try to save to cache.
I have mentioned my files below.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { CacheModule } from '@nestjs/cache-manager';
import { redisStore } from 'cache-manager-ioredis-yet';
import * as redisStore from 'cache-manager-ioredis';

@Module({
  imports: [
    CacheModule.register({
      isGlobal: true,
      store: redisStore,
      host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
      port: process.env?.REDIS_PORT
      ? Number(process.env?.REDIS_PORT)
      : 6379,
      ...(process.env?.REDIS_PASSWORD && {
        password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD,


      }),
      enableAutoPipelining: true,
    }),
    KnexModule.forRoot(knex_config),
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      envFilePath: !ENV ? '.env' : `.env.${ENV}`,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [{
  ...List of providers
 }],
})
```

**app.service.ts**

```
import { CACHE_MANAGER } from '@nestjs/cache-manager';
import { Cache } from 'cache-manager';


@Injectable()
export class AwsService {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(AwsService.name);

  constructor(
    @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private cacheManager: Cache
  ) { }

  async getCount(): Promise<Object> {
    try {

      const count = 10;
      await this.cacheManager.set(`count`, count, { ttl: 3600 });  
      
      const cachedNotification = await this.cacheManager.get(`count`);
      console.log(cachedNotification);
      return 'Success';

    } catch (error) {
      this.logger.error(error.message);
      throw new HttpCommonException(error);
    }
  }
}
```